# Puppet agent failing

Tags: puppet

I am not able to get puppet agent running.

I've tried removing `/etc/puppet/ssl` on the client, and `./puppetca --clean` on the server.  Nothing worked.

```
notice: Starting Puppet client version 2.6.8
debug: Using cached certificate for ca
debug: Using cached certificate for nysv0194
debug: Using cached certificate for ca
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect': certificate verify failed     (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:772:in `get'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:75:in `find'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:188:in `find'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector.rb:50:in `find'
     ... 10 levels...
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:305:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:411:in `exit_on_fail'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:305:in `run'
    from /usr/sbin/puppetd:4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosts were out of NTP sync :P

Answer (score 2):

it is

```
puppetca --clean full.host.domain.com
```

Also are you running the client as root?

Answer (score 2):

Here the certificates are kept on `/var/lib/puppet/ssl`, but I assume yours is on `/etc/puppet/ssl`. The thing is, was the puppet client *stopped* when you removed that directory? Because if it wasn't, you'd get such problems indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it ended up being due to having multiple versions of puppet installed: one from the Ubuntu repositories and one from a ruby gem.  Uninstalling the version from the Ubuntu repository solved the problem.