# puppet startup error

Tags: puppet

For some reason, not able to start puppet client... Have removed /var/lib/puppet and /etc/puppet/ssl... resigned the cert, same problem....

```
puppetd --no-daemonize --debug --server puppet
debug: Failed to load library 'shadow' for feature 'libshadow'
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file roleadd does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: true value when expecting false
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
debug: Failed to load library 'rubygems' for feature 'rubygems'
debug: Failed to load library 'selinux' for feature 'selinux'
debug: Puppet::Type::File::ProviderMicrosoft_windows: feature microsoft_windows is missing
debug: Failed to load library 'ldap' for feature 'ldap'
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys/nysv0194.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/nysv0194.pem]: Autorequiring         File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/log/http.log]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/log]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys/nysv0194.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/log]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_yaml]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/client_data]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/namespaceauth.conf]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/puppet.conf]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state/graphs]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/state]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/run/agent.pid]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/run]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/run]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: Finishing transaction 23845218561660
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/log]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/namespaceauth.conf]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/nysv0194.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys/nysv0194.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/log/http.log]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet/log]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/run]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys/nysv0194.pem]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]
debug: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Autorequiring File[/etc/puppet/ssl]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Autorequiring File[/var/lib/puppet]
debug: Finishing transaction 23845217700680
debug: Using cached certificate for ca
debug: Using cached certificate for nysv0194
debug: Finishing transaction 23845218414120
notice: Starting Puppet client version 2.6.8
debug: Using cached certificate for ca
debug: Using cached certificate for nysv0194
debug: Using cached certificate for ca
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect': certificate verify failed     (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:772:in `get'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:75:in `find'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:188:in `find'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/indirector.rb:50:in `find'
     ... 10 levels...
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:305:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:411:in `exit_on_fail'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:305:in `run'
    from /usr/sbin/puppetd:4
```

Comment: What is the operating system? How did you install it?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/294340/puppet-agent-failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that it can talk to puppet:8140 correctly, and check that the server is definitely working OK. (If this is your first client, maybe the server-side SSL stuff is broken?)